# Flexslider manual controls when clicked make slider blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

http://dev-examsoft.gotpantheon.com/

I have a flexslider on this when I click on buisness or any tab it goes blank.I am using manual controls to control the slider. Anyone encountered this problem before.